# What prevents $K^0$ from decaying into $K^+ e^- \overline{\nu}_e$?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

Energetically it is just possible for a neutral kaon to decay into a charged kaon, electron and antineutrino, namely:

$$K^0 \rightarrow K^+ e^- \overline{\nu}_e$$

Indeed a mass difference of a few MeVs exists between neutral and charged kaons. This decay would be similar to the usual semileptonic decay, which involves a $\pi^+$ instead of $K^+$. Correct me if I'm wrong. What does prevent this decay from being observed?

Comment: Are there other examples of strangeness-preserving weak decays in systems with nonzero strangeness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K_{long}$ [decays weakly to](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/tables/rpp2014-tab-mesons-strange.pdf)

[image: klong]

The mass difference with the charged Kaon is of order 4Mev. I think it is a matter of very small phase space which cannot give a measurable probability for the channel. Certainly 4 MeV energy shared with an antineutrino would not be detectable  in an experiment measuring $K_{long}$ decays.One would have to identify  a $K+$ , plus an electron of very small momentum associated with that. A specialized experiment would have to be devised since the phase space of the interaction is very small.